# Insert item after all children (org-mode)

Tags: org-mode

In `org-mode`, is there a way to insert an item *after* all of its children? Instead of the default behavior that inserts an item after the current item but before its children?

#### Example

Say I am in this list with the point at `X`.

```
  - A X
    - 1
    - 2
  - B
  - C
```

If I run the command `org-insert-item` (interpreted from `M-return`), then it produces the following.

```
  - A
  - X
    - 1
    - 2
  - B
  - C
```

What I would *like* to produce is the following.

```
  - A
    - 1
    - 2
  - X
  - B
  - C
```

This seems very similar to `org-insert-heading-respect-content`. I couldn't find anything like `org-insert-item-respect-content`, though.

Answer (score 2):

`org-M-RET-may-split-line` is the variable that will give the behavior you're looking for.

```
Documentation
Non-nil means M-RET will split the line at the cursor position.

When nil, it will go to the end of the line before making a
new line.
You may also set this option in a different way for different
contexts.  Valid contexts are:

headline  when creating a new headline
item      when creating a new item
table     in a table field
default   the value to be used for all contexts not explicitly
          customized
```

Quick solution to try it out: set that to `((default))`

Better solution: customize it to be nil in the `item` context, something like `((default . t) (item . nil))`.

---

Yes, this ought to be cleaned up a bit to match the `-respect-content` convention for heading behavior. If you get the time, please submit it to the org-mode issue list.